# Display XML in texteditor (eg. tinymce,Jquery Editor) PHP

Tags: php, xml, tags, tinymce, text-editor

I am using Jquery text editor. I copy and paste the XML as given below in texteditor

```
<shoes>
   <shoe>
     <shouename>Shoue</shouename>
   </shoe>
</shoes>
```

Then I click on save and the XML saved in Mysql DB. Then when I edit the same I see "Shoue" in texteditor field. But i want to show it as it is as below in texteditor

```
<shoes>
   <shoe>
     <shouename>Shoue</shouename>
   </shoe>
</shoes>
```

I think texteditor endering the XML with HTML.
How can I show XML as it is in texteditor using PHP. So that I could edit the XML and save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) and read about XSS - you should use this function always when you want output user's data on HTML page.
As variant, try Twig templates engine - very simple and have built-in escaping.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My mistake was I didn't use htmlentities() while inserting the data to DB. Now it's working.